# Как распознать битый/не докачанный файл на python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Как определить mime-type файла на python3 я знаю, и есть случаи, когда битые/не докачанные файлы не содержат mime-type, тогда их можно автоматически распознать через скрипт.

Но чаще всего, есть случаи, когда файл битый/не докачанный, но содержит корректный mime-type. Кто-нить встречал решение как определить битый или не докачанный файл с помощью python3 ? Или это в принципе невозможно?

Уточнение:
есть 3TB HDD, на нём куча фото/фидео не скачанных из инета, а сделанных на зеркальную фотокамеру и видеокамеру. Диск походу умирает, и нужно бы перенести небитые файлы на другой диск, а битые пропустить (или потом думать, как их восстановить). Просто взять скопировать всё - не вариант - копируются и битые файлы, а ручками перебирать всё - слиииишком много времени уйдёт. Вот и подумал, что можно обойти рекурсивно все каталоги hdd и найти битые фото/фидео файлы. А о не докачанных файлах упомянул, потому, что такую проблему тоже может кто встречал, она просто схожа.

Comment: Распознать недокачанное видео в общем случае невозможно, так как видео может быть в пригодном для стриминга формате, для которого недокачка — абсолютно корректная и обычная ситуация, из-за которой файл битым не становится. Хотя, к примеру, у некоторых mp4-файлов moov atom находится как раз в конце, и такие видео можно проверить с помощью того же ffmpeg например

Answer (score 1):

Ответ подсказал Andrey Dugin @adugin Куратор тега Python с toster.ru, а я "уточнил" код:

```
# Используем: https://scikit-image.org/
# Установка:
# pip install scikit-image
from skimage import io

def verify_image(img_file):
    try:
        io.imread(img_file)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Изображение {img_file.name} повреждено")
        return False
    return True

with open("IMG_20170805_083757.jpg", "rb") as f:
    verify_image(f)
```

Хотя ответ конечно не полный, т.к. это только для img, а с видео файлами - надо ещё искать решение. Но уже хоть что-то...